# How to send string to arduino from raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, arduino

I have an Arduino microcontroller (Adafruit feather M0), and if I have it plugged into my windows PC and open the serial monitor, I can type `P 0 2 1 0` and then `enter`, the Arduino interprets this command and works as expected.
Now I want to plug in the same device into my raspberry pi, and have python do this instead.
I have done this in the past on a different microcontroller (sparkfun pro micro) and it worked great. I can't seem to get it to work and am not sure what I am missing.

python code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout = None)
time.sleep(2)

returnKey = "\r\n"
ser.write(str.encode("P 2 1 0"))
ser.write(str.encode(returnKey)
```

The code finishes, but the Arduino simply does nothing, as if it discarded the command or didn't get it at all.
The serial speed is matching on the Arduino too (115200).

I also tried:

```
ser.write(b'P 2 1 0')
ser.write(returnKey.encode())
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Maybe you can try debugging it by sending back the serial data that you have read on Arduino to Raspberry pi and check if the characters are correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Ended up using

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout = None)
time.sleep(2)

ser.write(b'P 2 1 0 \r\n')
```

Comment: I believe the issue stems from the str.encode() call in your previous version. str.encode() defaults to "utf-8", and your MCU likely needs it in ASCII as str.encode("ascii"). Your second example works because it converts the given characters to binary ASCII.